# Every $\kappa$-metrizable space has countable $o$-tightness.

Tags: general-topology

> The $o$-tightness of a space X is said to be countable (notation: $ot(X)\leq\omega$) if whenever a point a belongs to the closure of $⋃γ$ , where $γ$ is any family of open sets in $X$, then there exists a countable subfamily $η$ of $γ$ such that a is in the closure of $⋃η$.
>   $\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$

**Lemma 4.** in this [article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864183900512) says that, Let $X$ be a $\kappa$-metrizable space, Then $ot(X)\leq\omega$.

**Proof**. Let us fix a $\kappa$-metric $\rho$ on a space $X$. Let $\gamma$ be a family of open subsets of $X$ and $x\in \cl(\bigcup\gamma)$. Then for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a finite subfamily $\gamma_\epsilon\subseteq\gamma$ such
that $$\rho(x, \cl(\bigcup\gamma_\epsilon)) < \epsilon\;,$$ (see [3, Lemma 4](http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1379054776)). Put $\mu=\bigcup\{\gamma_{\frac{1}{n}}:n\in\omega\}$. Then $\vert \mu\vert\leq\omega$
and $\rho(x, \cl(\bigcup \mu)) = 0$, i.e., $x\in \cl(\bigcup\mu)$. Consequently $ot(X)\leq\omega$.

I fail to understand how [3, Lemma 4] implies that $\rho(x, \cl(\bigcup\gamma_\epsilon)) < \epsilon$. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\gamma'=\{\operatorname{cl}U:U\in\gamma\}$. Since $x\in\operatorname{cl}\bigcup\gamma$, $\rho\left(x,\operatorname{cl}\bigcup\gamma'\right)=0$. Let $\epsilon>0$; Lemma $4$ of $[3]$ then says that there is a finite $\gamma_\epsilon\subseteq\gamma$ such that

$$\rho\left(x,\bigcup\gamma_\epsilon'\right)<\rho\left(\operatorname{cl}\bigcup\gamma'\right)+\epsilon=\epsilon\;.$$

where $\gamma_\epsilon'=\{\operatorname{cl}U:U\in\gamma_\epsilon\}$. Then

$$\bigcup\gamma_\epsilon'=\bigcup\{\operatorname{cl}U:U\in\gamma_\epsilon\}=\operatorname{cl}\bigcup\gamma_\epsilon\;,$$

since $\gamma_\epsilon$ is finite, and

$$\rho\left(x,\operatorname{cl}\bigcup\gamma_\epsilon\right)<\epsilon\;.$$

Comment: Every open set is regular closed?

Comment: @TXC: Oops! I misread the definition of $\gamma$. I’ve fixed it now, I think.